# Compress a file with password- encryption not supported

Tags: encryption, zip, solaris

I am going to compress some .csv file in one file, but I have to set password for this.

I have used zip -P password file.zip myfiles
but it gives me an error...

zip error: Invalid command arguments (encryption not supported)

I am working on Solaris machine. 
Could someone help me about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way

7z a -p[password] -r Fdirectory.7z /path/to/F